# How can I return a value from this static method?

Tags: php

I'm trying to return a value from the static method below checkForDuplicateUniqueId()

Let's assume that there's an existing $uniqueValue in the db table and what we want as the new unique value is 2

```
$uniqueValue = 1;

public static function checkForDuplicateUniqueId($table, $columnName, $uniqueValue, $db) {

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`$columnName`) as noOfResults FROM `$table` WHERE `$columnName` = '$uniqueValue'";

    if($db->fetchOne($sql)['noOfResults'] < 1) { // not found

        return $uniqueValue;

    } else {

        $uniqueValue++;

        self::checkForDuplicateUniqueId($table, $columnName, $uniqueValue, $db);

    }
```

If I echo the unique value from the first condition in the if else statement (instead of returning it), it will output 2, which implies that the recursion is occurring as expected i.e.

```
if($db->fetchOne($sql)['noOfResults'] < 1) { // not found
  echo $uniqueValue;
}
```

This is how the method above is called:

```
echo Helper::checkForDuplicateUniqueId('issue_materials_log', 'date', $timeStamp, $this->db);
```

The echo statement above outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `else` part. Do this:

```
return self::checkForDuplicateUniqueId($table, $columnName, $uniqueValue, $db);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I intend to. S/O doesn't allow you to accept an answer until a couple of minutes have passed since you asked the question.